# Transition effect not working for dynamic height

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a collapse component, but the transition effect is not working when i open and close the collapse component.

index.js

```
const Collapse = ({ title, text, child, ...props }) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggleCollapse = () => setIsOpen((isOpen) => !isOpen);
  const closeCollapse = () => setIsOpen(false);

  const content = useRef(null);

  const isParentOpen = props.isParentOpen;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isParentOpen) closeCollapse();
  }, [isParentOpen]);

  const height = !isOpen ? "0px" : `auto`; // ${content.current?.scrollHeight}px

  return (
    <CollapseContainer>
      <CollapseButton isOpen={isOpen} onClick={toggleCollapse}>
        <CollapseTitleWrapper>{title}</CollapseTitleWrapper>
      </CollapseButton>
      <CollapseContent ref={content} max_height={height}>
        <CollapseText>
          {text}
          {child?.map((datumn, index) => (
            <Collapse
              {...datumn}
              key={`collapse-child-${index}`}
              isParentOpen={isOpen}
            />
          ))}
        </CollapseText>
      </CollapseContent>
    </CollapseContainer>
  );
};
```

I think the height calculation should happen when the nested child also gets opened and closed.

Working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-monad-1m068)